# Reactjs - How to render a text and change size of it on mouse scroll (increment/decrement)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent, mouselistener

Using Reactjs how to render a text on the page where text size should change with mouse scroll (increment/decrement)

Comment: Please add more details. You just repeated the title in your question.

Comment: Are you talking about zooming in and out ?

Answer (score 0):

I think creating the React component with a state built like such:

```
state = {
    fontSize: 11
}
```

And then use the native onwheel event to bind the mousewheel to this state https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onwheel.asp

Then, in your text, presuming it is in a

```
<p> TEXT HERE </p>
```

tag and you are using JSX, you could write this as:

```
<p style={{ fontSize: this.state.fontSize }}> TEXT HERE </p>
```

This will make the text react to your state changes. As long as you bind the onwheel event to the react state correctly, this should work!